# Android - show progress dialog in imageView (as empty view) until image is downloaded from server

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, progressdialog

I have a view pager which shows downloaded images from server. While the images are being downloaded I show an empty stub as default.[image]

But instead of the stub i wanted progress dialog to be shown here until the image is downloaded. How can i do this?

image display method:

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Build a a progress dialog: `ProgressDialog.show(context,"loading","loading");`

Or

Place the `ImageView` along with a `ProgressBar`(preferably the intermediate spinner) in a `FrameLayout` and switch their visibility via `setVisibilty()`.

Comment: but how can i show progress dialog inside image view (considering your first option in the answer) .?

Comment: @sureshcheemalamudi nope, you can't. But you can show a layout that looks like one, from inside the `FrameLayout`, but that would just confuse the user.